# Starting QEMU as another user

Tags: networking, sudo, qemu, kvm, su

I'm currently trying to intercept/block specific requests from the guest in QEMU.
According to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251721/how-to-disable-qemu-guest-access-to-host-ports), it seems that the easiest way to do so is to run QEMU as a different user, so that I can differentiate between host and guest traffic in iptables.

However, starting QEMU as a different user always fails:

```
❯ sudo -u qemu-user qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm ...
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

gtk initialization failed
```

Any idea how to fix this, or what other method I could use to block guest traffic to e.g. a specific port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to connect to your local X11 server but doesn't have access; you can change this with the `xhost` command:

```
❯ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
❯ export DISPLAY=:0

sudo -E -u root qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -serial mon:stdio -m 8g -smp 4 -hda ~/Downloads/debian-12-generic-amd64.qcow2 -nic user,model=virtio-net-pci
```

works for me, also the `GTK initialization failed` error is a clue; it's trying to connect to an X server but can't because you need to allow the user and specify the location as an environment variable `DISPLAY=:0` (default)

be sure to read the man page on the `xhost` command and what `xhost +` does when you don't specify a username (it allows any.) Generally this is okay but I just want to make sure you understand this.

```
OPTIONS
       Xhost accepts the following command line options described below.  For security, the options that af‐
       fect  access control may only be run from the "controlling host".  For workstations, this is the same
       machine as the server.  For X terminals, it is the login host.

       -help   Prints a usage message.

       [+]name The given name (the plus sign is optional) is added to the list allowed to connect to  the  X
               server.  The name can be a host name or a complete name (See NAMES for more details).

       -name   The given name is removed from the list of allowed to connect to the server.  The name can be
               a host name or a complete name (See NAMES for more details).  Existing  connections  are  not
               broken, but new connection attempts will be denied.  Note that the current machine is allowed
               to be removed; however, further connections (including attempts to add it back) will  not  be
               permitted.   Resetting the server (thereby breaking all connections) is the only way to allow
               local connections again.

       +       Access is granted to everyone, even if they aren't on  the  list  (i.e.,  access  control  is
               turned off).

       -       Access is restricted to only those on the list (i.e., access control is turned on).

       nothing If no command line arguments are given, a message indicating whether or not access control is
               currently enabled is printed, followed by the list of those allowed to connect.  This is  the
               only option that may be used from machines other than the controlling host.
```

EDIT **

to block guest traffic to a specific port; use usermode networking, eg: `-nic user,model=virtio-net-pci` will give you a guest isolated network and you can control port forwarding via the qemu monitor (enabled with `-serial mon:stdio` you can switch between serial and the qemu monitor mode with `control-a-c` see also `hostfwd_add`:

more info: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_(SLIRP)

https://github.com/paigeadelethompson/docker-solaris#networking

Comment: you can also just use -monitor instead of -serial mon:stdio if that makes it any easier to get started with user networking; I typically enable -serial mon:stdio because I also use -nographic -nodefault and boot headless (console over serial) to avoid using X11 at all but its all up to you how you decide to use it, but for what it is worth that is typically how I use qemu

Comment: Thank you, `xhost` does the trick, but to further clarify my underlying problem:
I want to block the guest's **outgoing** requests to a specific port. More precisely, I'm trying to, unapparent to the guest, manipulate the system clock and need to block/redirect its NTP request/responses for that. So I'm looking for a way to block the guest's UDP request to port 123.